# Vue.js - Trying to pass object from data() to a mounted() function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to pass the grid array to the `createGridChart`, however, this is giving me an error:

> “grid is not defined”.

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        grid: [],
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.createGrid();
      this.createGridChart('grid-chart', 'pie', grid);
(...)
```

What would be the correct way to the the grid inside the function so that I can manipulate it to my liking?

Comment: You'd need to access it via `this.grid`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change `grid` to `this.grid`.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      grid: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.createGrid();
    this.createGridChart('grid-chart', 'pie', this.grid);
  (...)
```